# rewrite get_absolute_url method in a template- django 1.6.5

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there any other way of writing the get_absolute_url method in Django?
I wrote it in a template called **category_list.html**,stored in a directory named tags, as:

```
{% for c in active_categories %} 
<a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
<br /> 
{% endfor %}
```

and further, in another template named "**catalog.html**" I included the following line:
**{% include "tags/category_list.html" %}**

here's the implementation of get_absolute_url in the models.py:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('catalog_product', (), { 'product_slug': self.slug })
```

Also, here is what I have included in the urls.py file :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('catalog.views',
url(r'^$', 'index', {'template_name':'catalog/index.html'}, 'catalog_home'),
url(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'show_category', {'template_name':'catalog/category.html'},
    'catalog_category'),
url(r'^product/(?P<product_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'show_product', {'template_name':'catalog/product.html'},
    'catalog_product'),
```

)

It,however gives this error:
**NoReverseMatch at /catalog/**.
Is there another way of doing the same? Or the code I am writing is wrong, for django 1.6.5?

[Link to Image of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaWkY.png)

Comment: Please add your implementation of get_absolute_url - i.e. the model method. The error suggests there's something wrong there rather than in the template

Comment: You should post the whole error message, but it seems that the URL returned by `get_absolute_url` does not match any URLs configured in your urls.py. Can you post the code to your `get_absolute_url` method?

Comment: The error message in the screenshot says that no url matches `catalogue_category` for that slug. Do you have a url pattern with that name, and does it allow hyphens?

Comment: Are you sure the error is occuring where you use `{{ c.get_absolute_url }}`? The `get_absolute_url` method references `catalog_product`, but the error is for `catalog_category`. Where are you referencing `catalog_category`?.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to pass the name of the urls as an argument, when they should be a keyword argument, specifying `name`. So, an example would be as follows:

```
url(r'^$', 'index', {'template_name': 'catalog/index.html'}, name='catalog_home'),
```

So, now when you call from a view:

`reverse('catalog_home')` or from your template `{% url 'catalog_home' %}`

Django will search through your `urls.py` for a url with the name `'catalog_home'`, and correctly find it.

And Alasdair is correct that it was most likely a url found earlier in the template that threw this error, rather than where you thought the error occurred.

Also, somewhat unrelated, but the standard that you will find through out the Django docs, is to name your urls using dashes (`-`), rather than underscores. So `'catalog_home'` would be `'catalog-home'`

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou folks for help.
Writing the urls as `url(r'^$', 'index', {'template_name': 'catalog/index.html'}, name='catalog_home'),` and removing `@permalink` from the `get_absolute_url()` method definitions helped.
This code was written using a tutorial for the older version of Django,and @permalink is not used,or required anymore!
Instead, if one still wishes to use:

```
get_absolute_url = models.permalink(get_absolute_url)
```

with the get_absolute_function() definition (version 1.4 onwards).